# How to call an external API exactly once?

Tags: message-queue, worker, idempotent

Suppose we have a worker which is in charge of sending out payments.

Our worker, after deciding the money to be sent, calls an external Payment Service API.

The external Payment Service API provides no way to make our worker idempotent.

How to guarantee our worker is processing once and once only?

A possible solution is to accept there's no way to guarantee exactly once so we move to at most once approach and also implement a cron job to periodically check for payments that need to be sent out (possible manual human review needed).

How do payments in general handle this kind of stuff, in a world where external APIs don't provide idempotency mechanism?

Comment: It seems to me that a decent answer to your question would require specific details about the rest of your technology stack.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to guarantee exactly once if the external API doesn't provide an idempotent API. If the API provides a way to check if an operation succeeded then you can use it to decide if retry is needed.